# Send a DM to user that is not on the server with bot (discord.py)

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I want to create an invite DM that will invite the user to my server. Let's say I have their username and discriminator, how can I get the user itself to create a DM? Since this is an invite DM, the user that we are trying to find is not on the server.

Comment: Did you try the built in user converter? https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=userconverter#discord.ext.commands.UserConverter Sidenote: You cannot DM a user with your bot if the user and bot do not share at least one common server that they are in.

Comment: @moinierer3000 How do I use the method? I don't understand. Even if I can't DM user, I want to try to atleast get them.

Comment: The easiest way would be to use a type hint and let discord.py handle it automatically for you. For example if your command was called invite it would be  

`async def invite(ctx, user: discord.User)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As someone in the comments said, just use the built in `UserConverter.convert()` to get a user by Username and discriminator.

Also, your bot can't send DM's to a user that has no mutual server with the bot.